# How to send email with wp_mail() with from email taken from contact form instead of the host?

Tags: customization, email, wp-mail, contact

I have set up SMTL like this,

```
add_action( "phpmailer_init", "send_smtp_email" );
function send_smtp_email( $phpmailer ) {
ini_set("sendmail_from","xyz@gmail.com");
ini_set("sendmail_path","xyz@gmail.com");
    // Define that we are sending with SMTP
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    // The hostname of the mail server
    $phpmailer->Host = "localhost";
    // Use SMTP authentication (true|false)
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = false;
    // SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
    $phpmailer->Port = "25";
    // Encryption system to use - ssl or tls
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = "tls";

    $phpmailer->From = "xyz@gmail.com";
    $phpmailer->FromName = "XYZ";
    }
```

and added below code for my contact form to send email.

```
$headers = array('MIME-Version: 1.0'.'From: '.$_POST['namee'].'<'.$_POST['email'].'>'.'Reply-To: '.$_POST['email']);
$comment = $comment . "\r\n" . "\r\nIP Address: " . $id . "\r\nUser Agent: " . $browser . "\r\nReferrer: " . $referrer;
wp_mail($to,$website,$comment,$headers);
```

But, It is neither setting the headers properly nor does it send the email with the From address as the one taken from the contact form.

I'm getting emails but the From address in those emails is that of the host server.

I want that the email address taken from the contact form should get set as the From address in the email.

I know that there are hooks to replace the admin email and name, but, that replaces the site admin email address and name and become static. I want that the email address user enters in contact form should be the From address in the email being sent.

How can I do this? Does anybody know about it?

Comment: Are you sure you should be using `$_POST['namee']` and not `$_POST['name']`?

Comment: WP reserves $_POST['name'] and setting it causes trouble.

Comment: As Andy said $_Post['name'] is reserved by WP and hence I used namee

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the from name and email to PHPMailer in your code as it will take it from `$headers` so try the following:

```
add_action( "phpmailer_init", "send_smtp_email" );
function send_smtp_email( $phpmailer ) {
// ini_set("sendmail_from","xyz@gmail.com");
// ini_set("sendmail_path","xyz@gmail.com");
    // Define that we are sending with SMTP
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    // The hostname of the mail server
    $phpmailer->Host = "localhost";
    // Use SMTP authentication (true|false)
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = false;
    // SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
    $phpmailer->Port = "25";
    // Encryption system to use - ssl or tls
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = "tls";

    // $phpmailer->From = "xyz@gmail.com";
    // $phpmailer->FromName = "XYZ";
    }
```

Also, double check the form field name for: `$_POST['namee']`

Comment: I tried what you are suggesting, but in that case I am not receiving any emails.

Comment: I checked again and now without $phpmailer->From = "xyz@gmail.com";
    /and $phpmailer->FromName = "XYZ"; I'm not receiving any emails. Is there any way I can pass form input dynamically to these 2 options?

Comment: Hmm. Try this as your $headers: 
`$headers  = 'From: ' . $_POST['namee'] . '\r\n'; 
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['email']) . '\r\n'; 
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n"; 
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
`
or try with plain text instead of HTML mail.

Comment: Nope... That gives the same result!

Comment: What are your email headers from the email you receive?

Comment: Its the name from $phpmailer->FromName = "XYZ"; followed by an email address <host account name>@<hostsitename>.com for example, abc@yourwebhost.com. Its not even from my site.

Comment: And what is the content type, etc. I'm just trying to work out if it's an issue with your script or possibly something else doing it. The fact you have a different email address from another domain suggests that something else if causing the problem.

Comment: No reply to, no content type specifications in the header of the email delivered. The message body contains the IP address and user agent string of the client system and the referral URL along with the user's message text(this is simple and no html).

Comment: I read into this and found some good info here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9102/why-wont-wp-mail-let-me-set-the-from-header-when-plain-old-php-mail-will

And the following will explain the correct way to handle the user data:
https://www.sitepoint.com/handling-post-requests-the-wordpress-way/